# Need to Run MonadHandler but Return STM

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to execute a DB query, inside a websocket request. It's an adaptation of [this](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/e2e546df4d062e182da79a20115d1334055ee1a9/yesod-websockets/chat.hs#L31-L34) example.

To do so, I try to create a specialized `race_` - that will also have the `MonadHandler` which I'll use to query the DB. This results with the following non-working code:

```
    handlerRace_
        (forever $ atomically (readTChan readChan) >>= sendTextData)
        (sourceWS $$ mapM_C (\msg -> atomically $ do
            users <- lift (runDB $ selectList [] [] :: Handler [Entity User]) -- query the DB
            writeTChan writeChan $ msg
        ))

handlerRace_ ::  (MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadHandler m) => m a -> m b -> m ()
handlerRace_ = race_
```

and the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘t0 (HandlerT App IO)’ with ‘STM’
Expected type: STM [Entity User]
  Actual type: t0 (HandlerT App IO) [Entity User]
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  users <- lift (runDB $ selectList [] [] :: Handler [Entity User])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something (example code is not complete), but why not just put the `atomically` just on `writeTChan`, as this would be the intention for using STM (untested):

```
handlerRace_
    (forever $ atomically (readTChan readChan) >>= sendTextData)
    (sourceWS $$ mapM_C (\msg -> do
        users <- lift (runDB $ selectList [] [] :: Handler [Entity User]) -- query the DB
        atomically $ writeTChan writeChan msg
    ))
```

Comment: oh my, I hate being a newbie - silly mistakes... Thanks! :)
Also, once I put it out, I don't need a special `race_`

Comment: Don't worry, Haskell takes some time!